# Pandas Dataframe creating a unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:
[image]

I want to add each column, as `duration + credit_amount`, so I have created the following algorithm:

```
def automate_add(add):
  for i, column in enumerate(df):
    for j, operando in enumerate(df):
        if column != operando:
            columnName = column + '_sum_' + operando
            add[columnName] = df[column] + df[operando]
```

with the output:

[image]

1. duration_sum_credit_amount
2. duration_sum_installment_commitment
3. credit_amount_sum_duration
4. credit_amount_sum_installment_commitment
5. installment_commitment_sum_duration
6. installment_commitment_sum_credit_amount

However, knowing that `duration + credit_amount = credit_amount + duration`. I wouldn't like to have repeated columns. 
Expecting this result from the function:

1. duration_sum_credit_amount
2. duration_sum_installment_commitment
3. credit_amount_sum_installment_commitment

How can I do it?

I am trying to use hash sets but seems to work only in pandas series [[1]](https://realpython.com/python-sets/#defining-a-set).

***EDIT:***
Dataframe: https://www.openml.org/d/31

Comment: How does the output look like, can you post that too

Comment: @anky_91 added the photo of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been pointed already to `itertools.combinations`, which is the right tool here, and will save you some for loops and the issue with repeated columns. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) for more details about permutations, combinations etc.

First, let's create the DataFrame so we can reproduce the example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3],
    'b': [4,5,6],
    'c': [7,8,9]
})
```

```py
>>> df
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

Now let's get to work. The idea is to get all the `combinations` of the columns, then do a dictionary comprehension to return something like `{column_name: sum}`. Here it is:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({c1 + '_sum_' + c2: df[c1] + df[c2] 
                  for c1, c2 in combinations(df.columns, 2)})

    a_sum_b a_sum_c b_sum_c
0   5       8       11
1   7       10      13
2   9       12      15
```

Notice you can replace `sum` with any other function that operates on two `pd.Series`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am trying to see the documentation, but this is off for me. 
what is the `2` on the combinations? p.s.: Really easy to read and understand your code, thanks!

Comment: That's the beauty of python ;) `combinations(p,r)` creates all possible combinations of `r` elements out of an iterable `p`. In your case, the iterable is a list of columns of the DataFrame, and you want to obtain all couples (i.e. 2 elements, thence the 2) out of that.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the below, should work faster:

```
import itertools

my_list=[(pd.Series(df.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1),\
name='_sum_'.join(df.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(df.columns,2))]    
final_df=pd.concat(my_list,axis=1)
print(final_df)

  duration_sum_credit_amount  duration_sum_installment_commitment  \
0                        1175                                   10   
1                        5999                                   50   
2                        2108                                   14   
3                        7924                                   44   
4                        4894                                   27   

   credit_amount_sum_installment_commitment  
0                                      1173  
1                                      5953  
2                                      2098  
3                                      7884  
4                                      4873
```

**Explanation**:
`print(list(itertools.combinations(df.columns,2)))` gives:

```
[('duration', 'credit_amount'),
('duration', 'installment_commitment'),
 ('credit_amount', 'installment_commitment')]
```

Post that do :

```
for i in list(itertools.combinations(df.columns,2)):
    print(df.loc[:,list(i)])
    print("---------------------------")
```

this prints the combinations of columns together. so i just summed it on axis=1 and called it under pd.series, and gave it a name by joining them.

Post this just append them to the list and concat them on axis=1 to get the final result. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is really fast and is amazing. 
I have just 2 questions, there is a simple way to explain what is happening? what if I want to add multiplication, difference and ratio (*, -, /), I would change only the .sum(axis=1).

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis added in answer. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you @Anky_91 that helps a lot.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's the wrong way to use a list comprehension: you are initializing the list and then appending to it inside the list comprehension, whereas you should just use `my_list = [...]`.

Comment: @GiorgioBalestrieri you are correct, edited. :) Thanks i was testing with the Loops and just put that code without editing.

Answer (score 0):

The function can have one more if condition to check if the associate addition is already added as a column to dataframe like below:

```
def automate_add(add):
  columnLst=[]
  #list where we will add column names to avoid the associate sum columns
  for i, column in enumerate(df):
    for j, operando in enumerate(df):
        if column != operando:
            if operando + '_sum_' + column not in columnLst:
                columnName = column + '_sum_' + operando
                add[columnName] = df[column] + df[operando]
                columnLst.append(columnName)
```

I havent tested this on your data. Try and let me know if it doesnt work.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, because we are comparing the names and for a string 
`duration_sum_credit_amount != credit_amount_sum_duration `.I am going to see how to update the dataframe. The result: 

['duration_sum_credit_amount', 'duration_sum_installment_commitment', 'credit_amount_sum_duration', 'credit_amount_sum_installment_commitment', 'installment_commitment_sum_duration', 'installment_commitment_sum_credit_amount']

Comment: it is working. Thank you so much @Jim Tood. 
But I am quite confuse, how just changing the order of `operando + '_sum_' + column` made it work.  I have tested with more samples, and is working.

Comment: Yep.  Logic is,: if duration_sum_credit_amount is already created, there is no need for credit_amount_sum_duration to be created. So, only when if condition is True, (which means there is no column of vice versa already existing), a column is created. Else, no column with vice versa of existing column is created.